# U-SQL Insert data which is not present in existing file based on 3 unique columns

Tags: u-sql, azure-stream-analytics

```sql
@AllData =
    SELECT DISTINCT e1.[Createddate],
                    e1.Active,
                    e1.Model
                    e1.[ID]
    FROM @searchlog1 AS e1
       LEFT  ANTISEMIJOIN
             @searchlog AS t1 
         ON
t1.Active ==e1.Active AND
t1.Model == e1.Model AND
t1.[ID] == e1.[ID];
```

- `@searchlog1` is the old file
- `@searchlog` is the new file

We want to insert all the data from `@searchlog` file which is not present in `@searchlog1` file based on 3 unique columns. The above query is generating empty file

Comment: I mean your query reads the other way around, ie it reads as "get all records from @searchlog1 that do not exist in @searchlog" ?

Comment: @wBob i want to insert all the records from searchlog  which do not exists in searchlog1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert all records from `@searchlog`  that do not already exist in `@searchlog1` then simply swap your tables around - they are in the wrong order in your original statement as far as I can tell:

```
@AllData =
    SELECT DISTINCT e1.[Createddate],
                    e1.Active,
                    e1.Model
                    e1.[ID]
    FROM @searchlog AS e1
       LEFT  ANTISEMIJOIN
             @searchlog1 AS t1 
         ON
t1.Active ==e1.Active AND
t1.Model == e1.Model AND
t1.[ID] == e1.[ID];
```

`EXCEPT` won't work for this suggestion unfortunately as it requires the columns to match exactly instead of the four columns included in the original statement.

Comment: query which you shared is giving me all the records from new file which are already there in old file..

Comment: ah yes @wBob, all 3 columns need to be different. Will delete my answer then.

Comment: Can you supply some sample data and expected results because your question and statements are confusing.